# Two controls have names that contains same word are conflicting while filtering in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two textbox controls with name `dataexample` and `menuexample`. By default both are `display: none`. When I want one control to display then both are displaying by below code of jquery:

```
$('[name*="dataexample"]').css('display', 'block')
$('[name*="menuexample"]').css('display', 'none')
```

Comment: Pls add your generated html in question.

Comment: Check if both of your elements have same id.

Comment: Provide a [mcve] and proper explanation of behavior expected as it relates to the example. We can't guess what you need

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected. I've checked following html:

```
<input type="text" name="menuexample" style="display:none" value="menuexample"/>
<input type="text" name="dataexample" style="display:none" value="dataexample"/>
```

With following js code

`$('[name*="dataexample"]').css("display","block");
 $('[name*="menuexample"]').css("display","none");`

Please check your code and html again.